# Find all customization type mismatches?

Tags: customize

Occasionally, `defcustom`s change their `:type` and I fail to update my customizations. How can I get Emacs to list all the variables where customize things there's a type mismatch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with this:

```el
(defun my-custom-variable-valid-p (variable)
  (ignore-errors 
    (let ((w (widget-convert (custom-variable-type variable))))
      (widget-apply w :match (symbol-value variable)))))

(defun my-get-mismatched-variables ()
  (let (ret)
    (mapatoms
     (lambda (x)
       (when (and (custom-variable-p x)
                  (not (my-custom-variable-valid-p x)))
         (push x ret))))
    ret))

(defun my-show-mismatched-variables ()
  (interactive)
  (help-setup-xref (list #'my-show-mismatched-variables)
                   (called-interactively-p 'interactive))
  (with-help-window (help-buffer)
    (dolist (var (sort (my-get-mismatched-variables)
                       (lambda (a b)
                         (apply #'string-lessp
                                (mapcar #'symbol-name (list a b))))))
      (princ "* ")
      (princ (symbol-name var))
      (with-current-buffer standard-output
        (save-excursion
          (re-search-backward "* \\(.*\\)" nil t)
          (help-xref-button 1 'help-variable var)))
      (princ "\n"))))
```

You can then do `M-x my-show-mismatched-variables` to display a buffer with list of variables (symbols) whose values are mismatched. This list will include defcustoms that were declared with invalid `:type` as well. (Invalid `:type` is why I use `ignore-errors`).

Comment: Thanks, this doesn't seem to work though. After adding some missing `)`'s on the end, it always returns `nil`, even though I know I've set some incorrectly.

Comment: Sorry, when I edited it I accidentally deleted some parentheses, I fixed it now.

Comment: There are still quite a few false positives in there for me...

Answer (score 1):

The command `custom-invalid-vars` defined in the following elisp snippet displays a buffer with symbols of variables with mismatching customization.

Pityingly it also delivers some false positives.

`emacs-version`: GNU Emacs 25.1.50.2 (i686-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.10.8) of 2016-04-25

```el
(defun custom-invalid-p (symbol)
  "Return non-nil if SYMBOL has invalid customization."
  (when (get symbol 'custom-type)
    (let* ((type (custom-variable-type symbol))
       (conv (and type (widget-convert type))))
      (and (widgetp conv)
       (null (condition-case nil
             (widget-apply conv :match (symbol-value symbol))
           (error t)))))))

(defun custom-invalid-vars ()
  "Print list of variables with non-matching custom-type."
  (interactive)
  (let (ret)
    (mapatoms
     (lambda (symbol)
       (when (custom-invalid-p symbol)
     (setq ret (cons symbol ret)))))
    (when (called-interactively-p 'any)
      (with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create "*Custom: Invalid Vars*")
    (delete-region (point-min) (point-max))
    (insert (mapconcat #'symbol-name ret "\n"))
    (display-buffer (current-buffer))))
    ret))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use function **`custom-var-val-satisfies-type-p`** from library [**`cus-edit+.el`**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/cus-edit%2b.el) to get a list of options whose values do not match their custom types.

`C-h f custom-var-val-satisfies-type-p`:

> **`custom-var-val-satisfies-type-p`** is a compiled Lisp function in
>   [**`cus-edit+.el`**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/cus-edit%2b.el).
>
> `(custom-var-val-satisfies-type-p VARIABLE TYPES)`
>
> `VARIABLE` is bound, and its value satisfies a type in the list `TYPES`.

```el
(defun custom-mismatches ()
  "Show options whose values do not match their custom types."
  (interactive)
  (let ((vars  ())
        type)
    (mapatoms
     (lambda (var)
       (when (custom-variable-p var)
         (setq type  (get var 'custom-type))
         (unless (or (not type)
                     (custom-var-val-satisfies-type-p var (list (get var 'custom-type))))
           (push var vars)))))
    (pp-display-expression vars "*Custom Type Mismatches*")
    vars))
```

(The reason for checking that `(get var 'custom-type)` is non-`nil` is that the "type" `nil` is satisfied by any value.  If a `defcustom` does not actually use `:type` then the type is `nil`.)

See  [Customizing and Saving](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CustomizingAndSaving) for more about [**`cus-edit+.el`**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/cus-edit%2b.el).

Answer (score 0):

If the option, face, or Customize group is something defined by Emacs itself and not by a 3rd-party library then you can use command **`customize-changed`**:

> **`customize-changed`** is an alias for `customize-changed-options`.
>
> `(customize-changed &optional SINCE-VERSION)`
>
> Customize all settings whose meanings have changed in Emacs itself.
>   This includes new user options and faces, and new customization
>   groups, as well as older options and faces whose meanings or
>   default values have changed since the previous major Emacs
>   release.
>
> With argument `SINCE-VERSION` (a string), customize all settings
>   that were added or redefined since that version.

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking for something that lists only the customize options that are "mismatched," though, which this doesn't do (unless I'm misunderstanding something?)